# Scroll in navbar menu fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code (this is bootstrap fixed navbar menu):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid container_mop">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

            </div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="center img-responsive logo_top"></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left navbar_odstep">
                    <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">O mnie</a></li>
                    <li class=" mopy_menu_1 dropdown ">
                        <a href="#" class="mopy_menu_2 navbar_cor_1" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">gabinet <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownPadding">
                            <li class=" mopy_menu_dropdown"><a href="#">- Gdzie przyjmuje </a></li>
                            <li class=" mopy_menu_dropdown"><a href="#">- Badania </a></li>
                            <li class=" mopy_menu_dropdown"><a href="#">- Zabiegi</a></li>
                            <li class=" mopy_menu_dropdown"><a href="#">- Przygotowanie </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">Usługi</a></li>
                    <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">Cennik</a></li>
                    <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">Artykuły</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar_odstep">
                    <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


.navbar_odstep {
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
  }


  /*menu top*/

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
      color: white;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
      color: white;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
      color: white;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
      background-color: transparent !important;
      color: white !important;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
      background-color: #4B617F !important;
      color: white !important;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
      background-color: #4B617F !important;
      color: white !important;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-default .navbar-form {
      border-color: #3C4052;

  }

  .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #4B617F !important;
  }



  .navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-default .navbar-form {
      border-color: #3C4052;
  }

  .navbar-default {
      background-color: #3C4052;
      border-color: #3C4052;
  }

  .dropdownSelector {
      padding-top: 0px !important;
      position: relative;
      top: -4px;
      text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar_cor_1 {
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
      filter: alpha(opacity=1);
      -moz-opacity: 1;
      -khtml-opacity: 1;
      opacity: 1;
  }



  .mopy_menu_1 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: normal;
  }

  .mopy_menu_dropdown {
      text-transform: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: lighter;
  }

  .dropdownPadding {
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
  }




  @media screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
     .container_mop{
        width: 1750px;
         background-color: black;
    }
      .dropdown-menu:before {
      position: absolute;
      top: -17px;
      left: 10%;
      display: inline-block;
      border-right: 27px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
      border-left: 27px solid transparent;
      border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      content: '';
  }

  .dropdown-menu:after {
      position: absolute;
      top: -16px;
      left: 10%;
      display: inline-block;
      border-right: 26px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 16px solid #4B617F;
      border-left: 26px solid transparent;
      content: '';
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1700px) and (max-width: 1799px) {
    .container_mop{
        width: 1700px;
        background-color: red;
    }
}


@media(max-width: 480px) {

    .odstepNadMenuFront {
       background-color: red;
      height: 120px;
  }

    .logo_top {
      padding-top: 50px;
        width: 90%;
  }

  .navbar_odstep {
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

    .navbar_odstep{
        padding:0 ;
    }

}
```

When I have 480px width I have problem with scroll in menu (after click "gabinet" in menu - after open submenu). In desktop resolution I haven't any problems.

Screen with my problem: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERO6Z.jpg

Does anyone know how to fix it? The site uses Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-height` is specified in bootstrap so you need to overwrite it by adding below css

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

**LIVE SNIPPET**

```css
.navbar_odstep {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
 }


 /*menu top*/

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: white;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: white;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: white !important;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #4B617F !important;
  color: white !important;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  background-color: #4B617F !important;
  color: white !important;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
 .navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #3C4052;

 }

 .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4B617F !important;
 }



 .navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
 .navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #3C4052;
 }

 .navbar-default {
  background-color: #3C4052;
  border-color: #3C4052;
 }

 .dropdownSelector {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .navbar_cor_1 {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  -khtml-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
 }



 .mopy_menu_1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
 }

 .mopy_menu_dropdown {
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
 }

 .dropdownPadding {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 100% !important;
 }


 @media screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
  .container_mop{
   width: 1750px;
   background-color: black;
  }
  .dropdown-menu:before {
   position: absolute;
   top: -17px;
   left: 10%;
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 27px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
   border-left: 27px solid transparent;
   border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   content: '';
  }

  .dropdown-menu:after {
   position: absolute;
   top: -16px;
   left: 10%;
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 26px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 16px solid #4B617F;
   border-left: 26px solid transparent;
   content: '';
  }
 }

 @media(min-width: 1700px) and (max-width: 1799px) {
  .container_mop{
   width: 1700px;
   background-color: red;
  }
 }


 @media(max-width: 480px) {

  .odstepNadMenuFront {
   background-color: red;
   height: 120px;
  }

  .logo_top {
   padding-top: 50px;
   width: 90%;
  }

  .navbar_odstep {
   padding-top: 50px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .navbar_odstep{
   padding:0 ;
  }

 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid container_mop">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="center img-responsive logo_top"></a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left navbar_odstep">
        <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">O mnie</a></li>
        <li class=" mopy_menu_1 dropdown ">
          <a href="#" class="mopy_menu_2 navbar_cor_1" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">gabinet <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownPadding">
            <li class=" mopy_menu_dropdown"><a href="#">- Gdzie przyjmuje </a></li>
            <li class=" mopy_menu_dropdown"><a href="#">- Badania </a></li>
            <li class=" mopy_menu_dropdown"><a href="#">- Zabiegi</a></li>
            <li class=" mopy_menu_dropdown"><a href="#">- Przygotowanie </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">Usługi</a></li>
        <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">Cennik</a></li>
        <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">Artykuły</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar_odstep">
        <li class="mopy_menu_1"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```